# Is it possible to include graphics in lst-listing?

Tags: graphics, listings

I'd like to include an image within the `lst-listing`, but I'm not sure it is possible, as when I run the code below it gives

[image]

So is it possible?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\lstset{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,% basic font setting
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
R code
@
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by escaping to LaTeX code within the listing. You just have to choose some character(s) not used in your code proper. Here, I've used the pipe (`|`) as the escape character.

To get the background to appear properly, as discussed in Section 7.2 of the [`listings` package manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings), you must input the listing from a file and surround it with your favorite framing environment. Here I've used `mdframed` as shown in the manual. `listings`' built-in background has gaps around the escaped content.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my_r_code_test.r}
R code
@
|\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}|
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}

\lstset{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,% basic font setting
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}
Plain escapes (note gaps in background):
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=||]
R code
@
|\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}|
\end{lstlisting}

With \verb|mdframed|:
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!5,linewidth=0pt,%
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt]
\lstinputlisting[escapeinside=||]{my_r_code_test.r}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: link rot, here's another https://latex.ugent.be/files/documenten/listings.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Yes, indeed, using `escapeinside`, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=`']
R code
@
`\includegraphics{example-image}'
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\lstset{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,% basic font setting
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=`']
R code
@
`\includegraphics{example-image}'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is one problem - it doesn't quite look right. The image shows up way larger than normal, and it isn't within the gray box provided by `lstlisting`.